# para que sirve el Microsoft Graph API y el Azure Active Direcoty?

Tags: api, azure, microsoft, microsoft-graph

Que tareas se pueden cumplir, que cosas se pueden hacer leí toda la documentación de las `APIs` pero aun tengo mis dudas

Comment: Pero que necesitas hacer cual es el propósito de utilizar esto ?  puedes ser un poco mas descriptiva - aqui puedes encontrar un poco de documentación de tu pregunta (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview) sirve para manejar los servicios de Microsoft como correo, programación de reuniones muchas cosas es muy extensa la funcionalidad.

Answer (score 0):

**Que es Microsoft Graph:**

Microsoft Graph es una api para acceder a los datos de Azure Active Directory, los servicios de Office 365,los servicios de seguridad de Enterprise, los servicios de Windows 10, Dynamics 365

> Conectate a los servicios de microsoft y manipularlos mediante apis básicamente.

**Que es Microsoft Active Directory. Microsoft AD:**
Es un servicio multiusuario completamente administrado de Microsoft que ofrece capacidades de identificar loguearse y acceso para las aplicaciones que se ejecutan en Microsoft Azure y para las aplicaciones que se ejecutan en un entorno local.

> En microsoft AD tu puedes agregar usuarios o grupos de Usuarios y permitirle o negarle acceso, es como un panel de control de los servicios de Microsoft para tu empresa o grupo con el que trabajas.